# How do I catch and and log ALL exceptions/errors globally for a WebAPI 2 application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, error-handling, exception

I have a web API going in a live environment soon. I want to log all exceptions/errors globally.

I found multiple solutions online, some newer than others like using Elmah or 
doing a custom version using "Global error handling".

What is a reliable, painless solution to set up for this?

Comment: Define `painless`. What's wrong with the solutions you found online? And why are you threating logging as something you don't have to think about until just before going live? And what are you going to do with those logs?

Comment: To counter my somehow negative remarks, try Application Insights, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview

Comment: - painless is still are lative term to define, i means not writting hours on end for a solution.
- I didn't say there was something wrong, just a lot of different ways.. that's why I was asking for a direction to go in.. 
- thanks for the suggestion, but it helps only if you're on azure :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions depending on what you are looking for.

There are a few tools like Sentry that focus on exception tracking (Basically the Crashlytics, but for the web world). They focus a lot less on logs and mostly on uncaught (or sometimes caught exceptions). The pro is you don't have to code up many log messages and their tools can gather other context like the environmental variables or SDK versions.

There is also a group of tools that focus on logging. There is no SDK or agent unlike the first companies, rather they hook directly into the stdout/syslog outputs. Such companies would be Loggly and Logentries. These tools are designed more for searching millions of lines of logs.

There is also us (Moesif), we focus not on exception tracking, rather API errors and analytics by capturing context around API calls and the JSON payloads with them. While I work at Moesif, any of these options can be good and usually integrate pretty quickly. Each have 30 day to try, so sometimes you can try a few and see what fits in your workflow the best.